# Join 2 queries on same table and add column to result

Tags: mysql, join

I am pretty new to MYSQL and need assistance to complete a query.

I have 2 separate queries that I need put into just one query that I can use in PHP.

I am using the following SQL to get the number of records in a table called 'import' that have a Job_Completed_Date less than or equal to the Job_SLA_Due_Date.

My where clause checks for jobs done in the last 6 months in the 'import' table.

```
SELECT Year(job_completed_date), 
       Month(job_completed_date), 
       Count(*) AS Completed_On_Schedule 
FROM   import 
WHERE  job_completed_date >= Last_day(Now()) + interval 1 day - interval 6 month 
       AND job_completed_date <= job_sla_due_date 
       AND ( job_status = 'C' 
              OR job_status = 'C2' 
              OR job_status = 'C8' ) 
GROUP  BY Year(job_completed_date), 
          Month(job_completed_date) 
ORDER  BY job_completed_date ASC
```

The result output is fine and produces the following....

```
Year    Month  Completed_On_Schedule 
2017    3      1155 
2017    4      838 
2017    5      881 
2017    6      1095 
2017    7      1073 
2017    8      295
```

My second query is similar using the same table but I am looking for the total number of jobs that have been completed in the last 6 months but I am not worried about the Job_SLA_Due_Date. The SQL I am using is .......

```
SELECT Year(job_completed_date), 
       Month(job_completed_date), 
       Count(*) AS Total_Completed 
FROM   import 
WHERE  job_completed_date >= Last_day(Now()) + interval 1 day - interval 6 month 
       AND ( job_status = 'C' 
              OR job_status = 'C2' 
              OR job_status = 'C8' ) 
GROUP  BY Year(job_completed_date), 
          Month(job_completed_date) 
ORDER  BY job_completed_date ASC
```

The result output is as expected and produces the following.....

```
    Year  Month  Total_Completed 
    2017  3      1441 
    2017  4      1101 
    2017  5      1144 
    2017  6      1334 
    2017  7      1211 
    2017  8      311
```

What I need now is output like this......

```
    Year   Month Completed_On_Schedule Total_Completed %_On_Schedule 
    2017    3    1155                  1441            80.1 
    2017    4    838                   1101            76.1 
    2017    5    881                   1144            77 
    2017    6    1095                  1334            82 
    2017    7    1073                  1211            88.6 
    2017    8    295                   311             94.8
```

So in a nutshell I need to join my 2 queries together and add another column called %_Completed_On_Schedule which is the percentage of jobs completed on schedule i.e. the percentage that the Completed_On_Schedule column is of the Total_Completed column.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Regards

Alan

Answer (score 1):

Just use a conditional `COUNT` on your `SELECT`.

Aditional tip use `IN` instead of multiple `OR`

```
SELECT Year(job_completed_date), 
       Month(job_completed_date), 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN job_completed_date <= job_sla_due_date 
                  THEN 1 END) as Completed_On_Schedule,
       COUNT(*) AS Total_Completed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN job_completed_date <= job_sla_due_date 
                  THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / 
       COUNT(*) AS Total_Completed as `%_On_Schedule`

FROM   import 
WHERE  job_completed_date >= Last_day(Now()) + interval 1 day - interval 6 month 
       AND job_status IN ('C', 'C2', 'C8') 
GROUP  BY Year(job_completed_date), 
          Month(job_completed_date) 
ORDER  BY job_completed_date ASC
```

For answer how you join two queries together here is an example (even when you don't need it for this case):

```
SELECT Q1.*, Q2.*
FROM ( <your first query> ) as Q1
JOIN ( <your second query> ) as Q2
  ON (Q1.year, Q1.month) = (Q2.year, Q2.month)
```

Comment: using sum instead of count for getting the completed on schedule count will also work.

Comment: @Acewin I add the `JOIN` version because even when isn't need for this case, it is what OP ask for, and maybe will be useful for him in another situation. I don't like use `SUM(1/0)` to count. If you are counting use `COUNT()`

Comment: yeah I realized. Thats why I had updated my comment.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback appreciate it a lot.
Your SQL however when run comes up with the following error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `_On_Schedule`

FROM   import 
WHERE  job_completed_date >= Last_day(Now()) ' at line 8

Any thoughts?

Comment: maybe the `%_` in the field name? try remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added in your query a column with the total, and a CASE clausule. Besides, i have removed the AND for the SLA because we have it in the CASE_

```
SELECT Year(job_completed_date), 
       Month(job_completed_date), 
       SUM(CASE 
               WHEN job_completed_date <= job_sla_due_date THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS Completed_On_Schedule,
       Count(*) AS Total_Completed
FROM   import 
WHERE  job_completed_date >= Last_day(Now()) + interval 1 day - interval 6 month  
       AND ( job_status = 'C' 
              OR job_status = 'C2' 
              OR job_status = 'C8' ) 
GROUP  BY Year(job_completed_date), 
          Month(job_completed_date) 
ORDER  BY job_completed_date ASC
```

Comment: you have missed the %age

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I am referring to your queries as `QUERY_ONE` and `QUERY_TWO`, you'll of course need to replace these references with the actual queries.

```
SELECT a.Year, a.Month, a.Completed_On_Schedule, b.Total_Completed, 
((a.Completed_On_Schedule / b.Total_Completed) * 100) AS `%_On_Schedule` 
FROM (QUERY_ONE) AS a JOIN (QUERY_TWO) AS b ON a.Year = b.Year AND a.Month = b.Month;
```

This query will join your two tables on rows matching on Year and Month, then extract the desired values from each table and create your percent on schedule column. You need to apply ticks to your %_On_Schedule name since % is a key term in MySQL, I would recommend not using this symbol for this reason but it isn't a big deal really.

Comment: Just be sure to multiply by `100.0` otherwise you get an integer division.

Comment: Ah right to get percent and not decimal, thanks for catching that.